# Intelephense 1.4 and higher don't show hover menus or goto function declaration

Tags: intelephense

I can't upgrade Intelephense higher than 1.3 because from 1.4 hover menus when I hover a function are gone, and also clicking a function won't take me to the declaration anymore.

As You can see, in version 1.3 when I hover a function I can see details about it.
[image: ver 1.3]

And since version 1.4 Hovering does nothing:

[image: ver 1.4]

I've disable all other extensions to check if there is an extensions conflict, but it didn't help.
I tried to remove the indexing and re-index, but it didn't help

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, answer found, thanks to Ben, the developer of Intelephense.

I needed to set
**"intelephense.environment.shortOpenTag": true**
To enable support for short php tags i.e `<? ?>`

I also needed to set included files directories for
**"intelephense.environment.includePaths"**